# Pandas Return Cell position containing string

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new to data analysis , I wand to find cell position which containing input  string.

example:

```
Price   | Rate p/lot |  Total Comm|
 947.2      1.25        CAD 1.25

 129.3      2.1         CAD 1.25

 161.69     0.8         CAD 2.00
```

How do I find position of string "CAD 2.00".
Required output is (2,2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace columns names to numeric by `range`, [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and for first occurence of value use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
d = dict(zip(df.columns, range(len(df.columns))))
s = df.rename(columns=d).stack()
a = (s == 'CAD 2.00').idxmax()
print (a)
(2, 2)
```

If want check all occurencies use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and convert `MultiIndex` to `list`:

```
a = s[(s == 'CAD 1.25')].index.tolist()
print (a)
[(0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Explanation:

Create `dict` for rename columns names to **range**:

```
d = dict(zip(df.columns, range(len(df.columns))))
print (d)
{'Rate p/lot': 1, 'Price': 0, 'Total Comm': 2}

print (df.rename(columns=d))
        0     1         2
0  947.20  1.25  CAD 1.25
1  129.30  2.10  CAD 1.25
2  161.69  0.80  CAD 2.00
```

Then reshape by `stack` for `MultiIndex` with positions:

```
s = df.rename(columns=d).stack()
print (s)
0  0       947.2
   1        1.25
   2    CAD 1.25
1  0       129.3
   1         2.1
   2    CAD 1.25
2  0      161.69
   1         0.8
   2    CAD 2.00
dtype: object
```

Compare by `string`:

```
print (s == 'CAD 2.00')
0  0    False
   1    False
   2    False
1  0    False
   1    False
   2    False
2  0    False
   1    False
   2     True
dtype: bool
```

And get position of first `True` - values of `MultiIndex`:

```
a = (s == 'CAD 2.00').idxmax()
print (a)
(2, 2)
```

Another solution is use [`numpy.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) for check values, `zip` values together and convert to `list`:

```
i, j = (df.values == 'CAD 2.00').nonzero()
t = list(zip(i, j))
print (t)
[(2, 2)]

i, j = (df.values == 'CAD 1.25').nonzero()
t = list(zip(i, j))
print (t)
[(0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what each line doing?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - Sure, give me some time.

Comment: That's great bro, what will you say about @MaxU answer?

Comment: I just see it and I add similar.

Comment: Hey , how can I provide list of string as an input here?

Comment: For second solution use `i, j = ((df.isin(['CAD 1.25', 'CAD3', 'CAD 45']))).values.nonzero()`

Comment: Thing is my search value is name of column. will it work for it?

Comment: How can I change it , so that it should return index even though it is column name.

Comment: Hello can I startswith in this case?

Comment: Sorry, give me a sec.

Comment: I check it now and need only `df.rename(columns=d).stack()` remove `rename(columns=d)`

Comment: How can I achieve the same result for cells that contain a substring? for example in this case just 'CAD' ?

Answer (score 9):

```
In [353]: rows, cols = np.where(df == 'CAD 2.00')

In [354]: rows
Out[354]: array([2], dtype=int64)

In [355]: cols
Out[355]: array([2], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Can I give list of strings as a input?

Comment: Can I search for column name?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare, it depends... What and how are you going to search?

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative:

```
def value_loc(value, df):
    for col in list(df):
        if value in df[col].values:
            return (list(df).index(col), df[col][df[col] == value].index[0])
```