# Return first cell containing string in Pandas DataFrame - most efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking for an efficient way to search a large DataFrame and return the row number of a cell containing a string. I have the below code which works, but just wondering if this is the most efficient way to do it, as it involves two "for" loops

In this example, I'm trying to find a cell containing "Car Type"

```
for row in range(df.shape[0]):  # Loop through rows
    for col in range(df.shape[1]):  # Loop through columns
        if df.iat[row, col] == 'Car Type':
            row_start: int = row
            break
```

It might be that for loops are actually quite fast on DataFrames, but from what I've read, it's better to use Pandas' inbuilt functionality as much as possible for efficiency, and I'm not sure if i'm making this more complicated than it needs to be

Edit: Solution ideally using the Pandas library only if possible

Comment: probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669667/pandas-return-cell-position-containing-string

Answer (score 2):

If you have the list of columns then you can do

> df.query('col_name' == 'Car Type')

If that is what you needed, you can achieve it by using this. If you need more clarifications feel free to add comments.

Comment: That's why I said if you know have the list of column names, you can use **df.query**, it works using that. Solution has a pre requisite condition.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Pandas solution - first reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then remove second level of `MultiIndex` and last filter `index` values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,'Car Type',0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
print (df)
   A  B  C         D  E  F
0  a  4  7         1  5  a
1  b  5  8         3  3  a
2  c  4  9         5  6  a
3  d  5  4         7  9  b
4  e  5  2  Car Type  2  b
5  f  4  3         0  4  b

r = df.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True) == 'Car Type'
out = next(iter(r.index[r]), 'no match')
print (out)
4
```

Numpy solution is better, if performance is important:

You can get position of first matched index values by comparing by 2d numpy array with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and then use `next` with `iter` for possible return default values if not matched values:

```
r, c = np.where(df.values == 'Car Type')
out = next(iter(r), 'no match')
```

If not default index values:

```
out = next(iter(df.index[r]), 'no match')
```

Comment: Questions which qualified for duplicates needs to be flagged for duplicates, There is already an answer for this question available in SO. Please.

Comment: @min2bro - Ya, it is possible, be free flag it.

Comment: I am 800 points away from flagging Questions for Duplicate, Please do the honor.

Comment: @min2bro - It is not problem add comment under question - it is dupe by this question.

Comment: Done, Looks like the original answer was by you.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance here - but is there a way to do it using Pandas only? Or is numpy an essential import? I don't know how to use numpy at all (only Pandas) so was ideally looking for a solution using Pandas only

Comment: @Jezrael, I think if OP gets some hint from the already existing answers then he should avoid entering a new question.

Comment: @jezrael, NP, Only objective to make SO Clean, Unique and better place for the new developers.

Comment: @jbentley - Can you add it to question?

Comment: @jbentley - it is used numpy, because it is faster like pandas. What is reason not use numpy?

Comment: @jezrael Pandas is easier for me to use, I don't yet understand numpy. Kind of regret asking the question now. I still don't really understand

Comment: @jbentley - added pandas solution